# Python script has no stdout when started via i3blocks

Tags: python, i3, stdout

In i3blocks, I have defined a block like this:

`~/.config/i3blocks/config`:

```
[test]
interval=persist
format=json
```

The corresponding executable script:
`~/.config/i3blocks/config.scripts/test`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from time import sleep

while True:
     print("test")
     sleep(5)
```

I intend to replace "test" with an actual JSON-String later, I just stripped it down to this version for debugging purposes.

When I execute this on the command line, `test` gets printed to `stdout` every 5 seconds, as expected. I can get the PID with `ps aux` and check `strace`:

```
$ sudo strace -p82267 -s9999 -e write
strace: Process 82267 attached
write(1, "test\n", 5)                   = 5
write(1, "test\n", 5)                   = 5
[...]
```

`ps aux` also shows me the other process that i3blocks has started. `strace` with that process gives me no output, and I don't understand why. The loop seems to be running, but there is no `stdout`. To verify this, I removed the loop and restarted i3blocks, and the process is not listed anymore.

Why is there no `stdout` when i3blocks starts the process, and what can I do about that?

**Edit:**

I let it run for a long while and just noticed: `strace` shows me that a whole bunch of text was dumped to `stdout` all at once:

```
$ sudo strace -p79878 -s9999 -e write
strace: Process 79878 attached
--- SIGSTOP {si_signo=SIGSTOP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=79873, si_uid=1000} ---
--- stopped by SIGSTOP ---
--- SIGCONT {si_signo=SIGCONT, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=79873, si_uid=1000} 
write(1, "test\ntest\n[...a big big block of output here...]test\ntest", 8194) = 8194
```

The SIGSTOP and SIGCONT also happened several times.

So it seems like the output is stored in some buffer for very long, and then dumped to `stdout` all at once at some point.

What can I do about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru)s comment, I found the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182537/write-python-stdout-to-file-immediately):

If I change `print("test")` to `print("test", flush=True)`, the output buffer gets flushed immediately after the print, which solves my issue.